# Android network application running a service

Tags: android, sockets, networking, service, adb

I have created an android application that runs a background service that does the following :

1) Asks a UDP server to send 100 packets to it

2) Receives packets in a while(true) loop

3) setSoTimeout is used so that the receive times out after 5 minutes and gets out of the loop

The above operations are repeated every 2 minutes. The application works totally fine when the phone is connected to the PC and each and every step is monitored using adb logcat but the application stops working when the phone is disconnected from the PC. Logging each step then in a file shows that the last step is the receive step after which the socket does not timeout. What could be a possible reason for it? Is there any other approach by which I can do the intended task at constant intervals? 
This is the run function of the thread that is started from the service :

```
   public void downlink() 
{
    String path = extStorageDirectory + "/" + appFolder + "/REP_DT_" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    if(!file.exists())
    try 
    {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String p = extStorageDirectory + "/Goonj/logtput.txt";
    try {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path,true);
            fw.write("\n\n");
            fw.close();             
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(120000);
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
            long id = System.currentTimeMillis();      
            byte[] sendData = createMessage(id,0,1400,150);     
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9010);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);      
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[10240];
            boolean flag = true;
            while(flag)//for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {      
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length); 
                writeToLog(p,"START");
                clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                writeToLog(p,"END");
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                String data = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
                System.out.println(data);
                fw = new FileWriter(path,true);
                fw.write(Long.toString(getSeqno(data)) + " " + Long.toString(time) + "\n");
                fw.close();
            }                               
        }
        catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
        {
            writeToLog(p,"SOCKET EXCEPTION HAS BEEN CAUGHT!!!" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            writeToLog(p,"IO EXCEPTION HAS BEEN CAUGHT!!!" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    catch(SocketException e){}
    //fw.close();
}
```

Comment: can you show some code for your service?

Comment: When running your program on unplugged device does it go to sleep (phone's display times out)?

Comment: @Patrick : This is the function that is called periodically from service that is run.

Comment: BTW, You do not actually catch any `SocketException`s, just suppress them.

Comment: Patrick - The code is working completel;y fine when the usb is connected. Disconnecting the usb causes problems. In general disconnecting the usb causes the thread to not run periodically as specified even if the thread just prints data to a file at constant intervals.